# Can you suggest mysql function like this?

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if this question is stupid. What I want to do:-

```
<---'type' is a parameter of my procedure--->
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE
  CASE type
    WHEN 'some' THEN `column1`='column1string'
    WHEN 'somestr' THEN `column2` = 'column2string' AND `column1` = 'column1string'
    WHEN 'somestring' THEN `column3` = 'column3string'
  END IF;
```

But I want to write more sql queries when using case statement:-

```
CASE type
 WHEN 'some' THEN SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `coumn1`='column1string';
 WHEN 'somestr' THEN SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `coumn2`='column2string' AND `column1` = 'column1string';
WHEN 'somestring' THEN SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `coumn2`='column2string';
END CASE;
```

How can I do this without writing the same query more times. because I have 40 strings like this for comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use boolean logic:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table1` t
WHERE (type = 'some' AND `column1` = 'column1string') OR
      (type = 'somestr' AND `coumn2` = 'column2string') OR
      (type = 'somestring' AND `coumn2` = 'column2string');
```

Comment: Woow. thank you tooo much. that is I want. you saved my time.